# Confusion about arguments sent to add_image_size

Tags: images, cropping

Looking at the documentation for Cropping Thumbnails when [adding new image-sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) makes me confused.

> Set the image size by cropping the image and defining a crop position:
>
> add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( top, left ) ); // Hard crop top left
>
> When setting a crop position, the first value in the array is the x
>   axis crop position, the second is the y axis crop position.
>
> x_crop_position accepts 'left' 'center', or 'right'. y_crop_position
>   accepts 'top', 'center', or 'bottom'.

By this `array(top, left)` wouldn't be "allowed" because top is only allowed by y-crop position ?

Comment: Please add quotes from pages in blockquote, and don't use bold wording unnecessary, it is taken as shouting if used inappropriately.

Comment: You actually have a valid point here. According to what the `$crop` parameter say, it should be `array(left, top)`, not `array(top, left)`. Can anyone collaborate on this?

Comment: Just a note to the moderators, I've added the tag wordpress.org as this is codex related question that I feel is valid, check my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @PieterGoosen said, your point is valid. A look into the source confirms that the codex description of [add_image_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) was wrong there. It was, because I changed it to be correct. That said, everyone can help improving the codex, you just need to register. You might want to take a look at [Contributing to WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Contributing_to_WordPress) for a introduction on how to do that, the first section is about the documentation aka codex.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! I would probably register for improving the codex as well.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, I wasn't hundred percent sure. +1 for this and the extra info you provided

Comment: My pleasure, I guess I was just a little bit quicker. Besides that, this just proofs once gain the beauty of open information collaborating systems. @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: @PieterGoosen Sure thing, this just made me curious, so took a closer look. Otherwise the same as I said in the previous comment..don't want to repeat myself here.

Comment: HAHAHA Understood!

Comment: @ialocin - yes of course. open systems usally makes things happen faster. Then there's always a discussion about what is best or not, but that is a whole another discussion that shouldn't take place here :-)